# 1 Gig LAN transfer speed on 12 MB/s

Tags: linux, networking, local-area-network, ethernet

I'm transfering files between 2 linux servers on the same network.
This is the Network configuration on both of them:

server 1:

> Settings for eth0:
>
> ```
>     Supported ports: [ TP ]
>     Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
>                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
>                             1000baseT/Full
>     Supported pause frame use: No
>     Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
>     Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
>     Advertised pause frame use: No
>     Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
>     Speed: 1000Mb/s
>     Duplex: Full
>     Port: Twisted Pair
>     PHYAD: 1
>     Transceiver: internal
>     Auto-negotiation: on
>     MDI-X: on
>     Supports Wake-on: pumbag
>     Wake-on: g
>     Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
>                            drv
>     Link detected: yes
> ```

server 2:

> Settings for eth0:
>           Supported ports: [ TP ]
>
> ```
>     Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
>                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
>                             1000baseT/Full
>     Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
>     Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
>     Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
>                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
>                             1000baseT/Full
>     Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
>     Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
>     Speed: 1000Mb/s
>     Duplex: Full
>     Port: Twisted Pair
>     PHYAD: 1
>     Transceiver: internal
>     Auto-negotiation: on
>     MDI-X: Unknown
>     Supports Wake-on: pumbg
>     Wake-on: g
>     Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
>                            drv probe link
>     Link detected: yes
> ```

Both servers connected to the same switch, which supported 1 Gig, with Cat5e / Cat6.

I really don't know what could possibly cause that speed.
I've read that maybe the 'auto-negotiation' configure may do it?
Can I check what is the negotiated speed then somehow?

Comment: What are you using to transfer the files?

Comment: Please detail your hardware config, switch model and the specific command are you using for the transfer.

Comment: Hi, I'm using 'rsync -avzh --progress' command. my switch is hp v1910-48g. I also just tried to replace the Cat 5e cable to cat7, same speed.

Comment: Update: I just remvoed the '-h' from the rsync command, and the speed is now on 40 MB/s... any explanation ?

Comment: Is this a principal rsync (ie, copying stuff over for the first time), or a simple check-for-a-few-added-files-and-copy-them rsync?  If the former, when you repeated the test without `-h`, did you first delete the destination tree?

Comment: Hi, this is a principal rsync, copying for the first time. is 40 MB/s is a good speed for 1 gb link?

Comment: And when you retested without the `-h`, did you first delete the destination tree (ie, rerun the copy from scratch)?

Comment: Hi, No, I did not delete the destination tree, But when I ran the command again, It's just continue from the point he stopped.. If I delete the destination tree, he will just copy from the beginning, no?

Answer (score 2):

To add to iwaseatenbyagrue's answer, there are likely several things going on here, and keeping your eye on what you're testing is important.

Firstly, the first run of `rsync` involves write overhead on the destination.  When a small number of large files are being copied, this is fairly cheap, assuming you have half-decent discs, though it can make things slower than your network would suggest.  When a large number of small files are being copied, this can be *extremely* expensive: each time a file is laid down on disc, the inodes must be updated, the directory file brought up-to-date, and so on, and this introduces latency.  The time required for these FS operations eats up time that could be used for copying more file contents, so your apparent throughput drops like a stone.

Secondly, the `-h` business.  When you kill an rsync halfway through then rerun it, the `rsync` starts from scratch again, but because rsync is wise to content that already exists on the destination side and does not recopy it, the apparent throughput will be much better, at least until it runs past the point where it stopped first time around.  Thus the first and second runs of rsync **with no other changes whatsoever** will likely differ considerably in performance.  Make sure you're comparing apples with apples before getting worried that the second apple is a funny colour, ie, orange.

You may also find that if your corpus of files to copy is a mix of small and large files, your rsync varies in performance depending on how far through the corpus it is; see above.

Upshot: **if you want to test your network, test only your network**, do not conflate other issues by picking a test that also tests your FSes, underlying storage devices, etc.  `netcat` is a very nice tool for removing as much extraneous material as possible from a network test, inasmuch as you can feed it incompressible data from `/dev/urandom` at one end, and shove that across a network with very little tool overhead (no compression, encryption, etc.).

Comment: I'd suggest, this on the client: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=16384 count=1638400 | nc 192.168.10.10 11211` and `nc -l 11211 > /dev/null` on the host 192.168.10.10

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but you might want to validate your network throughput alone, rather than using network + disk throughput (+ possibly other factors, like the encryption overhead if using rsync over SSH, compression overhead if you use compression, etc).

[iperf](https://iperf.fr/) is a good tool for doing that, and should allow you to confirm how your network performs, as opposed to how your end to end throughput performs.

I suspect that in your case (based notably on the differences you mention between rsync runs), your network throughput would end up being roughly what it should be, which would tend to point away from the network being your bottleneck - but that is pure speculation.

Comment: I was thinking about trying 'iperf', but the server i'm transfering files from, is currently in 'read-only' system, because of raid fail.. This is why I'm transfering all the files to another server. So I cannot install iperf on it..

Comment: Ah, right - then yes, iperf is kind of waste of time - I had thought the concern was that something was wrong with the network  - I didn't realise the context was needing to get the files from A to B before A fails. Maybe worth updating your question to mention this fact - it could help get some suggestions to improve your ability to pull the data ASAP.

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue whilst I agree that would be a good question, it's not *this* question.  We're not so fond of chameleon questions around here, where we solve one problem and the questioner mutates the question into their followup question, which then changes again as we solve the followup issue.  If the OP wants to ask about that, I think accepting an answer to this question and asking a new one that references this question is a better idea.

Comment: @MadHatter - thanks for correcting me. And I agree - although the comments to the question paint a different picture than the question itself does (and I was thinking of that overall), the question itself is about throughput. And, it turns out, network throughput is very likely not the actual issue here - so I guess this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue you put it very well indeed, thank you.